# Inserting filename into last column of csv file.

Tags: linux, bash, csv

I would like to insert the file name of a CSV file into the last column of the CSV file.

I found a successful windows batch file but I'm looking for a linux bash script.

I've enclosed the windows batch file:

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%c in ('dir/b/a-d *.csv') do (
  set FN=%%~Nc
  set /a N=0

  for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (%%c) do (
    set /a N+=1
    if !N! equ 1 (
      echo %%a, id > !FN!.csv
    ) else (
      echo %%a, !FN! >> !FN!.csv
    )
  )
)
```

Looking forward to solving this one.

Henry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple.

```
import sys
import glob

for filename in glob.glob(sys.argv[1]):
    file = open(filename)
    data = [line.rstrip() + "," + filename for line in file]
    file.close()

    file = open(filename, "w")
    file.write("\n".join(data))
    file.close()
```

Save as "csvadd.py". Then this command will add the filename to the last column (replace test.csv ofcourse):

```
python csvadd.py test.csv
```

**EDIT**

Changed the code, it should now work with everything the OS supports (wildcards, etc). It will now also directly write the changes back to the file. **USE WITH CAUTION**

Comment: Thank you.  Can I use wild card entry?   Ooops.  on the last column f the row.

Comment: tested again.  I used the command "python csvadd.py test.csv < test.csv"  Although i see the file name being added. It is not appearing on the file.

Comment: Checked wildcard.  No luck.  I should mention we have to do this for 88 files a day.

Comment: thanks it works nicely. I will work out a way to use it will a wild card entry.  any ideas?   I am thinking of a bash script.

Comment: I checked the program with the *.csv wildcard.  It added the filename to the first and not to the rest.

Comment: I have used a script to create another bash script to create the 88 commands per day and then execute the script. It works

Answer (score 3):

With (gnu)sed:

```
for file in *.csv; do
    sed -i "s/$/,$file/" "$file"
done
```

with POSIX sed:

```
for file in *.csv; do
    if sed "s/$/,$file/" "$file" > /tmp/"${file}".tmp; then
        mv /tmp/"${file}.tmp" "$file"
    fi
done
```

Comment: The gnu seed works but adds the file name into the second column of data, overwritting the original data.

Comment: POSIX does the same.    Both Script however add the correct data, but to the wrong colomn.   We  would like the data in the last column.  I have already built the data.  Both are in amend all file in folder.

Comment: The first $ should be escaped by putting \ in front of it.

Comment: @HenryLevine if your CSV files have DOS endings, working with a unix sed on them will insert the new stuff between the \r and \n, which will look strange on a terminal (the stuff after the \r is written on the same line in the output as the previous text, seemingly overwriting it). Using dos2unix on the file before it should fix it, or using `\r$` in the regular expression.